# Generic extended constraint in class inheritance not working

Tags: typescript

so i have those classes :

```
export abstract class Parent<T> {
    ...
    public abstract <C extends Parent<T>>clone(): C;
}
```

```
export class Child extends Parent<number> {
    ...
    public <Child>clone(): Child {
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

Which seems to be correct to me but i get this error :

```
Child is assignable to the constraint of type 'Child', but 'Child' could be instantiated with a 
different subtype of constraint '{}'
```

I understand that the compiler tries to tell me that the constraint might not be respected but i can't see how.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: That signature says "I can produce an instance of type `C` for any `C extends Parent<T>` that the *caller* specifies", which is really suspect.  Presumably you just want to produce the same type as the extending class, for which a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) might be more appropriate.  But even that doesn't work when you `return new Child()`; what happens if `GrandChild extends Child` and doesn't override `clone()`?  So I'd like a bit more details on your actual needs here.

Comment: Indeed, what i wanted was an abstract method which would return the type of the implementing class. If there was a `GrandChild` which doesn't override `clone()` i would want to only get a Child, but i see what you mean. I came up with a very simpler solution because i didn't know that you could override a method with a more constrained return type (see my answere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i came up with a simpler solution.
My real problem is that i didn't know that i could override a method and change the return type to a more constrained type.

So here is my solution :

```
export abstract class Parent<T> {
    ...
    public abstract clone(): Parent<T>;
}
```

```
export class Child extends Parent<number> {
    ...
    public clone(): Child {
        return new Child();
    }
}
```